# Unexpected text "NaN" appearing near y-axis of the Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

There is a unexpected text "NaN" appearing near the Y-axis of the chart when both the datasets(Capital and Expense) of a chart are hidden in chart created using Chartjs([Link](http://chartjs.org)) plugin. The **chartType** being used here is **horizontalBar** chart.

Also attached is a screenshot of how it looks when one of the dataset is hidden(Type 1) and the Type 2 shows the chart when both the datasets are hidden.

`Link to fiddle`[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uc64673u/)

Comment: `NaN` means not a number, it looks like you are doing some mathematical operations on a string which throws this error. The solution is to convert your `String` to `Number` before doing math. Can you please share your code?

Comment: Impossible to answer with the information given

Comment: Note if you are already converting your `String` to `Number` functions like `parseInt()` where the parameter STARTS with a string will return `NaN` (i.e. `parseInt("1asdf"); // returns 1` and `parseInt("asdf1"); // returns NaN`)

Comment: You will need to provide a jsfiddle or codepen or as a minimum your complete chart.js config (with data) for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Apologies for the wrong way of asking for help. Please find below a jsfiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/uc64673u/

In this fiddle on disabling the two datasets(Capital and Expense) the "NaN" text appears on the top-left corner.

Comment: I managed to solve the above issue by not allowing the user to hidden all the datasets at same time ie., atleast one active dataset at all times. Fiddle link is https://jsfiddle.net/znppphyf/1/

Thanks for your time folks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
This fix worked in chart.js version 2.5 (or lower), in version 2.6 they said it's fixed by default.

**OLD ANSWER:**

**Hello, just change to this: (notice my callback on xAxis)**

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Capital',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: 'Expense',
      data: [4, 8, 6, 14, 12, 6],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          //this will fix your problem with NaN
          callback: function(label, index, labels) {
            return label ? label : '';
          }
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Can't really explain why is displaying that 'NaN', I think it's still trying to display the ticks even when there is no data. So, in that callback you make sure that data is displayed only if exists.
I had the same problem on a chart and didn't found any answer anywhere, so this fix is something I came up with on the fly, but it's working. That callback is overriding ticks displayed data, so you can customize it as much as you want.

You can check this issue here too:
[Chart js Github](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3770)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the above issue by not allowing the user to hide all the datasets at same time ie., atleast one active dataset at all times.

```
Fiddle link below
```

http://jsfiddle.net/znppphyf/1